# Display typescript error in html in Intellij/Webstorm

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

Is it possible to setup Intellij to display TypeScript errors in Angular template? I have the following dummy app shared on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p9ha5a). If I create a `@Input` with optional object parameters and use it in the template, I've got an error in console, but Intellij is ok with that. No error whatsoever. Note, I have strict mode on:

*tsconfig.json*

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
}
```

*data.ts*

```
export interface Data {
  id?: number;
  title?: string;
}
```

*data.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
})
export class DataComponent {
  @Input()
  public data?: Data;
}
```

*data.component.html*

```
<p>{{data.title}}</p>
```

*terminal output*

[image]

*template open in Intellij*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this currently, please vote for [WEB-49062](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49062) to be notified on any progress with this feature